# System.ArgumentException: options cannot be a cancellation token

Tags: c#, azure, c#-4.0, botframework, chatbot

I have a Chatbot using the Microsoft Bot framework using C# language and I'm facing a problem that says: options cannot be a cancellation Token.

```
var dialogCtx = await dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
if (dialogCtx.ActiveDialog == null)
{
    await dialogCtx.BeginDialogAsync(MainDialog.Id, cancellationToken);
}
```

this is the line code that the error is at.

Comment: Is that the **exact** error message?

Comment: You are passing it as the wrong parameter `await dialogCtx.BeginDialogAsync(MainDialog.Id, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext.begindialogasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Oh, the pitfalls of multiple optional parameters, especially when the first one is `object`....

Comment: @Charlieface Yuck

Answer (score 0):

As [CharlieFace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) stated, your problem here is the method `BeginDialogAsync` has optional parameters.

When calling methods with optional parameters where the expected position of parameters is not in linear order, you need to specify the parameter name you are providing a value for:

Method signature [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext.begindialogasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable):

```
public Task<Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync (string dialogId, object options = default, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

What you need to change your code to for it to work:

```
// adding the parameter name before the parameter value
await dialogCtx.BeginDialogAsync(MainDialog.Id, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Comment: thank you I've tried it and it's working now

Comment: @hamzahjazi98 please accept the answer if it helped solve your problem.